# Go - how can i do this python code in go code?

Tags: python, windows, macos, go

How can i do this in Go language please? I have used Python 2.7, pywin32 for the win32com and the following code which works to trigger virtual keyboard press.

Python code works:

```
import time
import win32com
import win32com.client

shell = win32com.client.Dispatch('WScript.Shell')
shell.Run('chrome')    
time.sleep(0.1)

shell.AppActivate('chrome')
shell.SendKeys("www.stackoverflow.com", 0)
shell.SendKeys("{Enter}", 0)

time.sleep(4)
shell.SendKeys("{F11}", 0)
```

i am actually trying the same Python code in Go (for Windows and Mac), can anyone give me any example how exactly this can be done with Go?

[image]

Comment: Your python code will only work on Windows because of `win32com`. If I understand correctly you want an executable to start Chrome on `stackoverflow.com` in fullscreen. Is that correct?

Comment: Check [this](http://productforums.google.com/d/msg/chrome/eX15CQ602UQ/zckrLOqBU5gJ) out : make SO bookmark, go to `chrome://apps`, drag bookmark to make new app, right click + `Open full screen`, right click + `Create shortcuts...`. `Create shortcuts...` seems to be only available on Windows though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't answer the win32 calls part, I assume you can do that via the syscall package, as in https://github.com/AllenDang/w32

As for launching chrome in full screen mode, you can do from a shortcut or if you really want to do it from go, you can do: [Play (can't run there)](http://play.golang.org/p/-SxmBd6ZsI)

```
package main

import "os/exec"

func main(){
    chrome := "C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe"
    cmd := exec.Command(chrome,"--chrome-frame","--kiosk","http://www.ibm.com")
    err := cmd.Start()
    if err != nil {
        println("Failed to start chrome:", err)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

win32 ole implementation for golang
https://github.com/go-ole/go-ole

Comment: Please provide essential details from link because link may get expired/redirect in future.